# symfony2 free -m out of memory

Tags: memory, symfony, ram

I have symfony2 app out there. But we have RAM memory problems... It works like a charm when there is 50 active people (google analytics).

I select data from DB usally like this:

```
        $qb=$this->createQueryBuilder('s')
         ->addSelect('u')
         ->where('s.user = :user')
         ->andWhere('s.admin_status = false')
         ->andWhere('s.typ_statusu != :group')
         ->setParameter('user', $user)
         ->setParameter('group', 'group')
         ->innerJoin('s.user', 'u')               
         ->orderBy('s.time', 'DESC')
         ->setMaxResults(15);

 return $query=$qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

The queries are fast i dont have problem with them.

Let me please know exactly what you need and i will paste it here. I need to fix it so much..

**BUT THE PROBLEM COME NOW:** When there is 470people at the same time.. (google analytics) there is about 7GB of memory away... then it fall down after peak to 5GB. But WHY SO MUCH??? My scripts take from 10-17MB of memory usage in app_dev.

I also use APC. How can i solve this situation? Why is there so much memory consumed? Thx for any advice!!

Whats your average memory?

BTW: When i will not solve this i will be in big troubles.

Comment: I have a bunch of Symfony2 apps in the wild, but none need anywhere near that amount of memory. Are you running APC?

Comment: Yes i am running APC.

Comment: You have a similar question before (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347256/symfony2-performance-ram-memory). I guess it's still the same problem: you are hydrating too much data. Show us some code how you retrieve data from db.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your stack? php-fpm? mod_php? and a little bit about how it's configured? in `ps axux` can you see which processes are using the RAM and how many of them there are? etc.

Comment: Hm... this is ps axux: http://www.upnito.sk/0/q464f4gfv9djbbs82j9h9dh8bk8kwnjq.png and about php-fpm and mod_php i dont know what to do or what you need so please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

One problem could be doctrine and if you are hydrating too much obejcts in every single request.

Comment: its kind a posiblle. But i am retrieving just what i need really. But i could specify certain columns in some queries to be withdrawn from DB and not whole table ... that would decreased the ammount of objects and hydrating right? Or what would u suggest?

Comment: I don't know your application, but LIMIT results and paginating in the user interface could be a starting point.

Comment: My every query for select has MaxResult ... And i dont use pagination.  I am making. I am selecting lets say "blogs" (15). Than i take all ids of these 15 blogs. And withdrawn comments from DB where blog id is in array of these 15 blogs. Is this ok? I need to it this way because somehow i modifiy in code the ID i need to select. This query is very very very fast btw.

Answer (score 1):

Set max execution time of a script to only 30 seconds:

```
max_execution_time = 30
```

Set APC shm_size to something reasonable compared to your memory:

```
apc.shm_size = 256M
```

Then optimize your query. And if you use php/symfony in cli, you better limit the resource usage for php in cli too.

Comment: What is shm_size for? And 256 is your suggestion based on my ram from screen?

Comment: It is the size of each shared memory segment in MB. By default, some systems (including most BSD variants) have very low limits on the size of a shared memory segment. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.shm-size)

Comment: But no, it's not my suggestion for your 8G memory (which is quite big). Use bigger, like 1G or 2G.

Comment: hm.. i am not sure how it will help reduce memory usage but i will give it try!

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you are understanding correctly memory consumption. http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2010/10/06/determining-free-memory-on-linux

To fast Apc you can remove the modified check with `apc.stat = 0` but you will need to clear apc-cache every time you modify existing files: http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.stat

To reduce memory consumption reduce hydration my adding `->select('x')` and fetching only the essential.

To optimize memory consumption enable mysql-cache, something like /etc/mysql/my.cnf:

```
query_cache_size=128M
query_cache_limit=1M
```

Do not forget to enable and check your slow-query-log to avoid bottlenecks.

Comment: He isn't trying to speed his application up, he's trying to reduce memory consumption... But the first link is useful!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your page has more that one query. How many queries happening on the page? Worst thing in the doctrine is the ability to make queries through getter(ex. getComments()). If you are using a many-to-many relation, this leads to huge problems. You can see all queries via profiler in dev environment.

Also possible, that problem in the settings of apache or php. Incorrect settings of php-fpm lead to problems too. The best solution is to stress test your server with tools like [siege](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/) and look what goes on through the htop or top. 300 peoples can be a heavy load for the "naked" apache

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried to retrieve scalar results instead of a collection of objects ?

```
// [...]
return $query=$qb->getQuery()->getScalarResult();
```

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#executing-a-query
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-result-formats

At symfony configuration level, have you double-checked your configuration to ensure caching has been enabled properly ?

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#caching-drivers

Detaching entities from your entity manager could prove useful depending on your overall process:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#detaching-entities

Comment: yes in few places of web i use getSingleScalarResult... about caching, my queries are cached i can see that.

Comment: Do you clear your entity managers regularly in your process?

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#detaching-entities

Comment: hm... no i never did it hm... do you think it take so much ram?

Comment: I could not tell the part of memory it takes to manage entities using entities managers (with regards to the overall consumption of your application since it might better need to be benchmarked), I would just say it depends on the number of instances which are handled simultaneously at any given time. You've mentionned 10-17MB using your development front controller (app_dev.php). What about the production one? Has any benchmark been made using tools like xhprof to spot quickly where the consumption comes from?

Comment: Its similiar to the dev inv because when 400 people come to web it takes 6GB of ram what is about 15MB on user... i didnt made any benchmark because i never did it before.. do you have some good tutorial for dummies ?  I will try it.

Comment: 15MB par user doesn't sound that excessive. I've just found this link which might be a bit outdated and yet convey useful pieces of information.

Comment: You  think it does not? Its social network so its very dynamic, i cached many things but still... and... what link ? didn't you forget to paste it?

Comment: Sorry, this link > http://techportal.inviqa.com/2009/12/01/profiling-with-xhprof/